# Polymorphic association in reverse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say that I have two models - one called **Post** and one other called **Video**. I then have a third model - **Comment** - that is polymorphically associated to to each of these models.

I can then easily do **post.comments** and **video.comments** to find comments assosciated to records of these models. All easy so far.

But what if I want to go the other way and I want to find ALL **posts** and **videos** that have been commented on and display these in a list sorted on the date that the **comment** was made? Is this possible?

If it helps I'm working on Rails 3 beta.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  named_scope :with_comments, :joins => :comments, 
                              :order => "comments.created_at DESC"
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  named_scope :with_comments, :joins => :comments, 
                              :order => "comments.created_at DESC"
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Now you can run these commands:

```
Post.with_comments
Video.with_comments
```

**Edit**
It looks like you want a single list with Videos and Posts. This is quite tricky, but doable. For every page you will have to execute 3 queries.

```
def commented_videos_posts(page = 1, page_size = 30)
  # query 1: get the lastest comments for posts and videos
  comments = Comment.find_all_by_commentable_type(["Post", "Video"], 
               :select => "commentable_type, commentable_id, 
                              MAX(created_at) AS created_at",
               :group => "commentable_type, commentable_id"
               :order => "created_at DESC", 
               :limit => page_size, :offset => (page-1)*page_size)

  # get the video and post ids
  post_ids, video_ids = [], []
  comments.each do |c|
    post_ids << c.commentable_id if c.commentable_type == "Post"
    video_ids << c.commentable_id if c.commentable_type == "Video"
  end

  posts, videos = {}, {}

  # query 2: get posts
  Post.all(post_ids).each{|p| posts[p.id] = p }
  # query 3: get videos
  Video.all(video_ids).each{|v| videos[v.id] = v }

  # form one list of videos and posts
  comments.collect do |c| 
    c.commentable_type == "Post" ? posts[c.commentable_id] :
                                   videos[c.commentable_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I want to combine the two? I want a list of both (combined) that is ordered by create_at? A merge if you will…

Comment: So you want ONE list with videos and posts ordered by last comment date? Do you want to get last n objects OR more? Do you need pagination and further filtering?

Comment: Exactly! And yes, pagination would be added also but my main problem is just how to combine the two lists… any clues?

Comment: Ah, nice, also a great solution! Thank you for time.

Answer (score 2):

probably not the best way, but this worked for me:

```
#get all posts and videos
posts_and_videos = Comment.all.collect{ |c| c.commentable }

#order by last comment date
posts_and_videos_ordered = posts_and_videos.sort{ |x,y| x.comment_date <=> y.comment_date }
```

hope this works for you too.

**EDIT**

i'm also assuming you're using `has_many :comments, :as => :commentable` and `belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true` like KandadaBoggu suggested.

**EDIT #2**

actually, i think i made a mistake and the code above won't work... try this:

```
(Comment.find(:all, :order => "comment_date")).collect{ |x| x.commentable }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'lll give that I try. And yes, the associations are set up correctly. :)